How to change active company for Tally?
I am using an ODBC connection to Tally ERP to fetch details from the application and show them on the website. I am facing issues when there are multiple companies in Tally. So, for example, SELECT * FROM "Company" gives me all values in the table for Company A, but I cannot get it for Company B. How do I achieve it?

As this is particular to the idiosyncrasies of the commercial product, Tally, you'll probably have better luck using Tally support channels.

How many databases do you have?  Are you connecting to the correct Database?  "Company" is a table in a database.  The table in the database you are using only has info from Company A and not Company B.  You either have to add Company B to the table or select a database that already has Company B in the table Company.

using odbc you can acess only data of company that is selected in tally, if you want to access data from companies that are opened in tally use xml approach

Hi @saivineeth, how can I achieve it using the XML approach? Is there any sample available?

if you are using C# then use TallyConnector library else Postman collection
